# i have writen this test for my check box input and it didnt simulate properly

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, karma-mocha

```
describe('<CheckBoxItem />', () => {
  it('<CheckBoxItem /> should exist', () => {
    const wrapper = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <CheckBoxItem name="test" text="text">
        <div>
          <label>
            <input className="input" type="checkbox" name={name}/>
          </label>
        </div>
      </CheckBoxItem>
    );
    const input = wrapper.input;
    expect(wrapper.state.value).toBe(false);
    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.change(input);
    expect(wrapper.state.value).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

i wrote this test and the simulate section wont work 
i googled over a week and cant find a solution

Comment: What do you expect with calling change method of test util?

Comment: Simulate only works with DOM elements, not React Components. So for instance, ReactTestUtils.Simulate(wrapper.getDOMNode());

Comment: i want my checkbox to change value i used click too but that didnt work